# Can an InDesign slideshow go on a website hosted with Google Sites?

Tags: google-sites

I'm using Google Sites to make my new photography website and I want to make an Adobe InDesign slideshow for it.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Google site is going to be a website, I don't think you'd be able to get an Indesign slideshow into it. You'd need to have a jQuery slider and slideshow. Search for it on Google, there are hundreds of different ones.

I'm not sure of your experience level with HTML, CSS, or jQuery. For a starting point, if your not interested in learning how to build websites from scratch and you just want to have your personal site up and running, I would look at purchasing a WordPress theme from [themeforest](http://themeforest.net/) or set up a Behance account and build a '[Behance pro site](http://prosite.com/?utm_source=network&utm_medium=footer&utm_campaign=network_footer_references)'. Another alternative is to build it with newly updated [Square Space](http://www.squarespace.com/). These are all excellent platform to build on and if you don't have a particularly technical background. out of the 3 Behance and SquareSpace are going to be the simplest to use..

Comment: Oh wow! I never knew about jquery! I'll get on this right away! Thank you :D

Comment: no worries glad i could help, if you liked the awnser please click the 'except the awnser tick', cheers